# rails and mongomapper one relation: creating new entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper, relation

i'm creating simple rails app with mongomapper to do some inventories: basically, i want to be able to define what the replacement unit should be.

so i have models:

```
class Replacement
  include MongoMapper::Document
  set_collection_name 'asset_replacements'
  key :device, String
  one :current, :class_name => 'Asset'
  one :replacement, :class_name => 'Asset'
end

class Asset
  include MongoMapper::Document
  set_collection_name 'assets__collection'
  key :_id, Mongo:ObjectId
  key :vendor, String
  key :model, String
end
```

and i have a form.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@replacement) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :device %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :device %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">      
    <%= f.label :current_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :current, Asset.sort(:model), :id, :model %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">      
    <%= f.label :replacement_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :replacement, Asset.sort(:model), :id, :model %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the controller is:

```
def create
  p = params[:replacement]
  @replacement = Replacement.new( p )

  respond_to do |format|
    if @replacement.save
      format.html { redirect_to @replacement, notice: 'Replacement was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @replacement, status: :created, location: @replacement }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @replacement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

the problem is that when i come to creating the new `Replacement` on the rails app, i get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in ReplacementsController#create
  undefined method `each_pair' for "50381cb24ed00a707c0000c1":String
```

it appears that i'm having difficulty with matching the string for the `replacement` and `current` to a useable mongo object.

i've tried doing a lookup with `Asset.find( BSON::ObjectId.from_string( p['current'] )`, which doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't appear to put the relations into the mongo collection.

what am i'm doing wrong?